# Escape ; (semicolon) in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

How do I escape the semicolon in `C:\;D:\;`?

```
Filename: "configFile.ini"; Section: General; Key: Ignore Drives; \
    String: C:\;D:\; Flags: createkeyifdoesntexist
```

Comment: Try this:  C:\;;D:\;; from what I know, you double the character to escape it.

Comment: I tried that and it does not work

Comment: Close your String in Double Quota ("). `Section: General; Key: "Ignore Drives"; String: "C:\;D:\;"; Flags: createkeyifdoesntexist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quote all strings (even if they do not contain semicolon):

```
String: "C:\;D:\;"
```

Read documentation on [section parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=params).